# How to execute a SSIS package stored in the server

Tags: c#, ssis, etl

I am trying to execute an SSIS package through a C# .NET code.

From the previous question I found this solution but when I execute this my package runs and ssisPackage.Execute() return "Failure" as a result.

Here is my code for executing the package.

```
        string pkgLocation = "D:\\Package.dtsx";
        Package ssisPackage;
        Application app;
        DTSExecResult result;
        Variables vars;

        app = new Application();
        ssisPackage = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation,null);

        result = ssisPackage.Execute();
        if(result== DTSExecResult.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Succesfull");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if(result== DTSExecResult.Failure)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

My SSIS package contains a connection to SQL server database.

Tech stack
Visual Studio 2017

SQL Server 2016

SSDT 2017

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio you can right-click a package and select Execute, then choose to script it to T-SQL instead of running it. You can then run the SQL as you would normally run any SQL from .NET. However, I don't know the reason for your failure so you may get the same result which means something else is wrong.

Comment: Is d: drive mounted on machine with SQL Server or on a different machine?  I would check the log file (LDF) on server to get more info.

Comment: @jdweng Can the reason for the failure be that I have not installed a local SQL server in the system I am currently trying to execute the program.

Comment: No.  You do have to install the utility.  See installation on following :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/dtutil-utility?view=sql-server-ver15  Once installed you need a credential that allows you access to database from a remote machine.  So if you can use SQL Server Management Studio on the remote machine to access the database you should be ok.

Comment: I finally found the error message. "The Script Task "ST_71d9425916264171ab93a0d340aad54d" uses version 14.0 script 
that is not supported in this release of Integration Services." I tried changing the targetServerVersion to SQL Server 2016 and recreate the script but I get the same error.